# Install php_mailparse extension on IIS Windows 2008 RS2

Tags: iis-7.5, php5, extension

I can't install the php_mailparse properly in a Windows Server 2008 RS2.
I have the error:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\ext\php_mailparse-php-5.4.3-Win32-VC9-x86.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

But this file exist. Please see attached screenshot.
[image]

Anyone can help? What could I try?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related with the type of the DLL, we must use the Non Thread Safe one instead the Thread Safe.